# create flexible array size in struct

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, struct, graph, adjacency-list

hi there I have these structs code 
I need to make my `head[]` array size flexible
for example, if my head array size is 9 how can I extend it to be 10 ?!

```
struct Graph
{
  // An array of pointers to Node to represent an adjacency list
  struct Node *head[N];
};

// Data structure to store adjacency list nodes of the graph
struct Node
{
  int dest, weight;
  struct Node *next;
};
```

how can I create a struct graph with a flexible head array size?

Comment: Are there any other fields in `struct Graph`?  If not, you don't need it.

Comment: If you use a Flexible Array Member struct, you can grow it with `realloc()`.

Comment: @dbush Although graph might not be needed I find it easier to store the head node pointer in a separate struct from the node when dealing with linked lists. It just seems easier to manage that way.

Comment: But what I don't understand is why do you have an adjacent list array when you're dealing with a linked list?

Comment: @Shawn and how can I push the new data to the newly allocated memory?

Comment: @Irelia i am building a directed graph with edges weights

Comment: `realloc()` copies the contents of the existing allocation to the new one if needed. See Ted's answer for an example.

Comment: @noorshein If there's something in my answer that you want me to describe in more detail, please just ask.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for you assistance i just don't understand how can I extend the graph and enter a new data 
kindly view this code in this link>> https://godbolt.org/z/bq4eYa717

Comment: @noorshein I don't see that you've made use of the a flexible array member in there at all. You are using a fixed size array and you are not allocating `Graph` like I showed in the answer. I cleaned that up [here](https://godbolt.org/z/dGG8GGn8T), but I don't understand how you connect things. Look at the debug printout I added at _point new node to the current head_. Does that look right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have succeeded to extend the graph, can you show me how can I insert  add a new vertical with new edges
    for example: 
     6 —> 4 (weight6) and delete  2 —> 0 (weight) ?

Comment: @noorshein It'd be best if you looked at my answer and asked me if anything is unclear. If you _do_ understand the answer, you should be able to use it in any situation where you need a flexible array. Also, I don't see the code where you have succeeded to extend the graph.

Comment: @TedLyngmo here is the code>>https://godbolt.org/z/MKPx36dvM
type the input>>A4n02533n20411n13702
here is an imageboard explaining more about how the code will work: https://ibb.co/5GRCmSh

Comment: @noorshein Sorry for the misunderstanding. I wasn't really asking for code to analyze. I just pointed out that it'd be impossible to do so without actually having access to it. What I want is for you to understand the answer and if it's not a clear answer to your question, I can try to improve the answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I fully understand your answer - extending the graph size

Comment: @TedLyngmo but i want to know now how can I insert the new node to the current graph for example >> the node 5->3(weight 7)

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks ted i will create new question for my new problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `struct` with a flexible array member usually has a member keeping track of what size the array is, so I'm assuming it looks like this:

```
struct Graph {
    size_t nodes;
    struct Node *head[];
};
```

To allocate memory for such a `struct` you would need to call `malloc` and sum up the `sizeof(Graph)` (where the extent of the flexible member is counted as `0`) and the `sizeof(struct Node*[the_number_of_node_pointers_you_want])`.

Example:

```
struct Graph *Graph_create(size_t nodes) {
    struct Graph *g = malloc(sizeof *g + sizeof(struct Node*[nodes]));
    if(g) g->nodes = nodes;
    return g;
}
```

If you later want to expand the flexible array, you could use `realloc` in a similar way:

```
// this returns true or false depending on if expansion succeeded
bool Graph_expand(struct Graph **g, size_t nodes) {
    if(*g && (*g)->nodes < nodes) {
        struct Graph *ng = realloc(*g, sizeof *ng + sizeof(struct Node*[nodes]));
        if(ng) {
            *g = ng;
            (*g)->nodes = nodes;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Pfhqe49o7)

A word of caution when it comes to expanding the array: `realloc` may move the memory if it can't expand the allocation in-place. If that happens and you have any pointers **to** your old `Graph` object, they will have been invalidated by that `realloc`.

Comment: do you know how can I free all the graph structures?

Comment: @noorshein Sure, for every pointer you get from a `malloc` you `free`. If you `realloc` that pointer, you `free` what's returned from the `realloc` instead. So, for every allocation there should be one free. It's a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: sorry but I do not understand, if I want to delete a specific head node with it is series how can I do that for example 2->5(weight 3)  head[2] and all nodes related to this head

Comment: can you vie my new topin for this issue here >>

Comment: can you view my new topic for this issue here>> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70523959/deleting-source-node-from-adjacency-list-and-all-related-nodes-to-the-source) and try to solve it?

Comment: @noorshein If you've asked a new self sufficient question, I'm sure it'll be answered. I may have the opportuinity to have a look at it later.